# Where do the stderr within the return value of subprocess.Popen() originate?

Tags: python, bash, subprocess, popen

I'm currently working with Python and Bash to run a backend of a web application. I've inhereted this project and am tasked to do modifications on it, therefore I don't have a good knowledge about what the person who wrote this code had intended to do, so sorry if my question seems a bit disconnected at places.

What I'm currently doing is using Python to call a subprocess via `.Popen()` which executes a Bash Script, after that, I use `.communicate()` on the return value of this subprocess to gather the `stdout` and `stderr` from it, if the later is not empty, I run checks on what it contains and act further accordingly.
However, it doesn't appear clear to me what kind of error is written into "`stderr`". Shouldn't an "`exit 1`" for example be logged in `stderr`? Does `stderr` only concern itself with errors that occur while executing `.Popen()`? And is there a way to have an error logged in `stderr` from inside the Bash Script that is being run?

Comment: Only those who can see the bash script can know for sure. Please search the web for the fundamentals on output redirection in bash. Once you have a grasp of that you can begin to understand how your python script interacts with the bash script.

Comment: `exit` does not print anything to standard error, but will reflect on the exit code (what you get from `p.wait()`). Unless you require the subprocess to run concurrently with your Python program, you should probably use `subprocess.run()` or similar, instead of directly talking to the low-level `Popen()` function.